# Insert a record if it does not exist in database and show a message to user if a record is already in database

Tags: sql, .net, windows, c#-4.0, ado.net

I want to insert a record if it does not exist in our database .If the data to be inserted already exist in database then  a messagebox should be displayed to user that the data that you want to insert is already in the database.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_InsertRoles
    (
@roleName varchar(50),
@roleStatus tinyint
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblRole WHERE roleName = @roleName and roleStatus=@roleStatus)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'FALSE'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblRole
        VALUES(@roleName,@roleStatus)
        SELECT 'TRUE'
    END
END
```

---

```
string cs = 
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["School_Management_System.Properties. 
        Settings.schoolManagementDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertRoles", con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roleName",txtRole.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roleStatus",ddlStatus.SelectedItem);

            con.Open();//connection open

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            if (count > 0)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Role already exits...", "Failed",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else if (count <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Role inserted successfully...", "Success",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            con.Close();
```

Comment: `INSERT .. FROM .. WHERE ...`. Add an `OUTPUT` clause after `INSERT` to return the new ID. If no value is returned, the row was already there

Comment: You can create a unique index on roleName (+roleStatus) so inserting same content will raise an exception that you can catch and inform the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use `using` blocks for you database objects. That will ensure they are closed and disposed even if there is an error. You will want to declare `count` outside of the using blocks so you can use it after the connection is closed. You don't want to show message boxes while a connection is open. Connections are precious resources and should be opened right before the `.Execute...` and closed as soon as possible.

Use the `.Add` method instead of `.AddWithValue` See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Since your stored procedure returns the strings True or False, I changed count to a boolean and adjusted tne `If` block.

```
    private void UpdateDatabse()
    { 
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["School_Management_System.Properties.Settings.schoolManagementDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        bool count;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertRoles", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@roleName",SqlDbType.VarChar, 50 ).Value = txtRole.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@roleStatus",SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = (int)ddlStatus.SelectedItem;
                con.Open();
                count = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
        if (count)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Role inserted successfully...", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Role already exits...", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
     }
```